# Deploy internal asp.net project in IIS with ssl

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, iis, active-directory, ssl-certificate

I am creating an internal application which will be published on the IIS server of an ad ds domain, this will be internal and therefore not accessible from the internet so I cannot obtain a certificate from a certification authority. I manage to put the project online on IIS and access it from my SSL port 44313, but then google chrome sends the message that the site is not recognized and is therefore not secure. Is there a way to make all browsers in the domain ad ds recognize the certificate as secure? thank you in advance!

Comment: "I cannot obtain a certificate from a certification authority." Well, you should learn how to set up your own CA on AD, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/install-the-certification-authority

Comment: thank you very much i didn't think that could do that

Answer (score 0):

The link is useful,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/install-the-certification-authority
If we want Google browser to recognize our server certificate(browser address bar will display a secure lock mark), we must install the server certificate on the client to the local certificate store(`Trusted Root Certification Authorities` or `Trusted people`) to indicate trust in the server certificate. In a simple case, we must install a single certificate one-to-one, if you want all machines in AD to trust the server, the best way is to install and establish a certificate authority in the domain, which will establish a certificate trust chain. Because every machine that joins the domain will contain the root certificate.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.